# Digital read from ADC2 pins when wifi enabled in ESP32

Tags: esp32

Is it possible to get a digital input from ADC2 (GPIO - 0, 2, 4, 12, 13, 14, 15, 25, 26, 27) when wifi is enabled in ESP32?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you would think it would not be possible? Note however that the ADCs in the ESP32 are quite noisy and inaccurate, so depending on your needs an external ADC may be better.